# jQuery: Replace strings with .each()

Tags: jquery, regex

I want a function that replace each li with an image. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tmphref;
    var tmpname;
    var str = '<a href="' + tmphref + '"><img src="http://www.somesite.com/a/' + tmpname[1] + '/avatar-small.jpg /></a>';
    $('#somediv li a').each(function(){
        tmphref = $(this).attr("href");
        tmpname = /http\:\/\/(\w+)\.somesite\.com\//.exec(tmphref);
        $(this).parent().replaceWith(str);
    });
});
```

The image is in this specific path: www.somesite.com/a/username/avatar-small.jpg
The code above doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move

```
var str = '<a href="' + tmphref + '"><img src="http://www.somesite.com/a/' + tmpname[1] + '/avatar-small.jpg /></a>';
```

after `tmphref` and `tmpname`, like this

```
$('#somediv li a').each(function(){
    tmphref = $(this).attr("href");
    tmpname = /http\:\/\/(\w+)\.somesite\.com\//.exec(tmphref);
    var str = '<a href="' + tmphref + '"><img src="http://www.somesite.com/a/' + tmpname[1] + '/avatar-small.jpg /></a>';
    $(this).parent().replaceWith(str);
});
```

because variable `str` is already assigned values with `undefined` `tmphref`, and `tmpname`, so changing the values of `tmphref` and `tmpname` after that, wouldn't effect the variable `str`

And, for that case, you don't need to declare variable for `tmphref` and `tmpname` outside `.each` function.

Comment: Exactly - you're setting the two variables _after_ you're using them. :)

Comment: That came into my mind, but isn't that declaring a new variable for every li? (it has the var keyword)

Comment: Warrantica, your `tmphref` is based on the each loop, so its needed to do it inside.